# Error after adding diacritics

Tags: unicode

I'm having a frustrating problem compiling a file with Czech diacritics.

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{notes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

% \includepdf{PDFs/Cover}
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofmyequations

\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{lecture1}

\end{document}
```

`lecture1.tex`:

```
\mainsection{1}{Lecture title}{dd/mm/yyy}

Hello ř
```

When I do not put `ř` into the file, it compiles fine. When added, it ends on following error message I cannot understand:

```
(./main.equ) [1] (./lecture1.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 Hello ř
```

All files are saved in UTF-8 (shown by VS Code).

Could you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to  your preamble.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}} \setcounter{page}{1}` and `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}} \setcounter{page}{1}, consider writing `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, respectively. (The `\pagenumbering` directive resets the `page` counter to 1 automatically.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with a standard class with any version of TeX Live I have. Of course, I don't have `notes.cls`. Can you please give a pointer to it?

Comment: @Bernard could you reproduce the problem? I do not see how adding `fontenc` could change the behaviour here (but I don't see how the reported behaviour could occur either)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought maybe  it used by default the OT1 encoding, and that was the cause of the problem, but I've just tested, and there's no problem. However, I had to modify the code, as I don't have the `notes` class installed (no idea where it comes from, so I replaced it with report), and of course, I don't have  the pdf file included. Might having `cm-unicode`  installed have helped my compilation?

Comment: @Bernard on the face of it it is an input enc error so font setup not involved at all but the error is not reproducible, i wondered if you had the notes class and it was doing something strange to account for this, but apparently not....

Comment: Hi all, this is the `notes.cls` file - https://gist.github.com/vojtechzicha/d3439ea83446ccabb9b4cd5794adc8db

The original help by @Bernard worked, but I cannot mark it as answered. Thank you all for help!

Comment: The simple solution is *not using* `notes.cls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `notes` class shown in the comments breaks almost every LaTeX accent command.  In particlular here it redefines `\v` to be `\boldsymbol{v}` which is not a v accent and is a math mode command so generating the error you show.

A simpler example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\v}{{\boldsymbol v}}

\begin{document}

Hello  ř

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7 Hello  ř
             
?
```

The only real fix is to not use this `notes` class (which has several other errors besides this), however if you must use it, edit `notes.cls` to remove or comment out this section

```
% NO!: % bold letters (useful for random variables)
% NO!: \renewcommand{\a}{{\boldsymbol a}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\b}{{\boldsymbol b}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\c}{{\boldsymbol c}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\d}{{\boldsymbol d}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\e}{{\boldsymbol e}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\f}{{\boldsymbol f}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\g}{{\boldsymbol g}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\h}{{\boldsymbol h}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\i}{{\boldsymbol i}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\j}{{\boldsymbol j}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\k}{{\boldsymbol k}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\m}{{\boldsymbol m}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\n}{{\boldsymbol n}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\o}{{\boldsymbol o}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\p}{{\boldsymbol p}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\q}{{\boldsymbol q}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\r}{{\boldsymbol r}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\s}{{\boldsymbol s}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\t}{{\boldsymbol t}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\u}{{\boldsymbol u}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\v}{{\boldsymbol v}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\w}{{\boldsymbol w}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\x}{{\boldsymbol x}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\y}{{\boldsymbol y}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\z}{{\boldsymbol z}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\A}{{\boldsymbol A}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\B}{{\boldsymbol B}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\C}{{\boldsymbol C}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\D}{{\boldsymbol D}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\E}{{\boldsymbol E}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\F}{{\boldsymbol F}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\G}{{\boldsymbol G}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\H}{{\boldsymbol H}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\I}{{\boldsymbol I}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\J}{{\boldsymbol J}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\K}{{\boldsymbol K}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\L}{{\boldsymbol L}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\M}{{\boldsymbol M}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\O}{{\boldsymbol O}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\P}{{\mathbb{P}}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\Q}{{\boldsymbol Q}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\R}{{\boldsymbol R}}
% NO!: \renewcommand{\S}{{\boldsymbol S}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\T}{{\boldsymbol T}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\U}{{\boldsymbol U}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\V}{{\boldsymbol V}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\W}{{\boldsymbol W}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\X}{{\boldsymbol X}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\Y}{{\boldsymbol Y}}
% NO!: \newcommand{\Z}{{\boldsymbol Z}}
```

Comment: Also the lines `\newcommand{\calA}{{\cal A}}` and similar should be dealt with. Not to mention loading `latexsym` and `times` and a wealth of unprotected endlines.

Comment: @egreg yes, actually I think I'll amend to say "don't use this class, or if you must, remove...